# Medrash, Witness and G-d

Tags: midrash

I heard someone mention that the *Medrash* teaches us, *“[If] You are My witnesses... and I am G-d,” but, “If you are not My witnesses... I am not G-d.”*

Do you know where this *Medrash* is from?

Answer (score 2):

The verse is a verse in Yeshaya 43:12, and the Medrash is from [Sifri Devarim psikta 346](http://books.google.com/books?id=6SI9AAAAcAAJ&pg=PT295&lpg=PT295&dq=%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%9D%20%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99&source=bl&ots=uE8n0pxCPA&sig=Sc634jDB-wnVhLeksyIknMLYjPE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TTkFVN7LCdLoggS28oHwAQ&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%20%D7%95%D7%99%D7%94%D7%99%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9F%20%D7%9E%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%90%D7%AA%D7%9D%20%D7%A2%D7%93%D7%99&f=false).

> אם אתם עדי הרי אני א-ל, ואם אין אתם עדי, כביכול אין אני א-ל

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah I had it right originally, it was _pesikta_ 346.  It's to the posuk ויהי בישורון מלך.  I couldn't find it on wikitext so I thought I messed it up but I found it on google books. Link is linked in post now.

Comment: Did I say you were wrong?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah No I thought I was after you asked for a link and I couldn't find it on wikitext.  Now I corrected myself.

Comment: YEZ, the medrash - Devarim Rabbah - is quoting psikta 346?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Where did Devarim Rabba get involved?

Comment: So then the medrash is quoting psikta 346. What is name of the medrash? (i.e. a medrash in bereishis) Is it a pesikta or pesikta rabbah?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah The medrash is Medrash Sifri.  ספרי דבי רב.  It's not quoting a different medrash, it _is_ the medrash.  See [here](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99).

Comment: Where in the Sifri Devarim does it quote Pesikta 346?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah It is one sefer.  The Sifri Devarim is divided into pesiktas.  It is not one sefer quoting another.  This is the primary source.  This is it. You open Sifri Devarim and you turn to Pesikta 346.

Comment: So it's Sifri Devarim, Pesikta V’Zvos HaBrachah 346, correct?

Comment: @ChiddusheiTorah Yes, although V'Zos HaBeracha should really go before pesikta, if you want to include it.  Sifri Devarim (V'Zos HaBeracha) Pesikta 346.

Comment: Thanks! Have a good morning. May Hashem prescribe and seal all of klal yisrael to merit and "see" this year the coming of Moshiach and the rebuilding of bayis shlishi!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16853/discussion-between-chiddushei-torah-and-yez).